# jQuery scroll down page not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, frontend

I am trying to make a smooth scroll effect for my page using jQuery. Does anyone know why this doesn't work?

```
$(document).ready(function() {


   $("#button").click(function() {
     $(document).animate({
       scrollTop: $("#endpoint").offset().top
     }, 1100);
   });

 });
```

The JSFiddle -> https://jsfiddle.net/1hm56tms/2/

Answer (score 0):

You should animate the Body and not the document.

```
$("#button").click(function() {
   $("body").animate({
   scrollTop: $("#endpoint").offset().top
 }, 1100);
```

});

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/1hm56tms/3/)

Answer (score 0):

### You need to change document to body or html,

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/1hm56tms/4/)

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $("#button").click(function() {
        $('html, body').animate({
           scrollTop: $('#endpoint').offset().top}
        , 1000);
    });

});
```